# Titan: comparison between two query approach

Tags: titan

What is the performance difference between

```
g.query().has("city","mumbai").vertices().iterator().next();
```

here each vertex will have a property `city` with city name `mumbai`

and

```
v.query().direction(Direction.IN).labels("belongTo").vertices();
```

here `v` is the vertex for `mumbai` city and all other vertex is connect to it through edge label `belongTo`.

I want to do query something like `all vertex having city mumbai`. Which approach will be better?

The problem is a user can enter anything as city name e.g mumbai or mummbai or mubai so its not possible to varify city name. So for `mumbai` i will create `mumbai` `mummbai` `mubai` vertex. its very inefficient.

How will you handle this kind of situation?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by `g.getVertex("mumbai")`. That isn't a valid for vertex lookup (titan expects a Long for an id and it is an identifier generated by Titan and can't be assigned).  Can you please clarify?

Comment: I update my question as per u said

Answer (score 2):

Titans ElasticSearch integration is great for those kind of fuzzy searches. Here's an example:

```
g = TitanFactory.open("conf/titan-cassandra-es.properties")
g.makeKey("city").dataType(String.class).indexed("search", Vertex.class).make()
g.makeKey("info").dataType(String.class).make()
g.makeLabel("belongsTo").make()
g.commit()

cities = ["washington", "mumbai", "phoenix", "uruguay", "pompeji"]
cities.each({ city ->
  info = "belongs to ${city}"
  g.addVertex(["info":info]).addEdge("belongsTo", g.addVertex(["city":city]))
}); g.commit()

info = { it.getElement().in("belongsTo").info.toList() }

userQueries = ["mumbai", "mummbai", "mubai", "phönix"]
userQueries.collectEntries({ userQuery ->
  q = "v.city:${userQuery}~"
  v = g.indexQuery("search", q).limit(1).vertices().collect(info).flatten()
  [userQuery, v]
})
```

The last query will give you the following result:

```
==>mumbai=[belongs to mumbai]
==>mummbai=[belongs to mumbai]
==>mubai=[belongs to mumbai]
==>phönix=[belongs to phoenix]
```

Cheers,
Daniel

Comment: yah thats good.What I found that if you only to query about a particular city then `v.query().direction(Direction.IN).labels("belongTo").vertices();` is just too good but if you want to search city along with other field like `country` `product title` `price` then `has()` will be too good with ES